# How to port Slick 2.1 plain SQL queries to Slick 3.0

Tags: scala, slick

The following working code from Slick 2.1 returns a single integer (which in this example, happens to be the result of running a function called "foobar"):

```
def getFoobar(): Int = DB.withSession {
   val query = Q.queryNA[Int]("select foobar()")
   query.first
}
```

How would one port this to Slick 3.0?   According to the Slick 3.0 docs, the query would have to be converted to an DBIOAction.  So this is what I've tried:

```
import driver.api._

...

def getFoobar(): Future[Int] = {
   val query = sql"select foobar()".as[Int]
   db.run(query) 
}
```

but this results in the following compilation error:

```
[error]  found   : slick.profile.SqlStreamingAction[Vector[Int],Int,slick.dbio.Effect]#ResultAction    [Int,slick.dbio.NoStream,slick.dbio.Effect]
[error]  required: MyDAO.this.driver.api.DBIO[Seq[Int]]
```

It appears that the sql interpolator is yielding a `SqlStreamingAction` rather than a `DBIO`, as `db.run` is expecting.

What would be the correct way to write this in the new Slick 3 API?

Comment: So one thing that seems a bit off is that it requires `Seq[Int]`, can you maybe try changing your as to `.as[Seq[Int]].head`? According to the docs your query should work, so not sure what other issues there might be.

Comment: After a bit of experimenting, I've gotten `sql"select foobar()".as[Int].head` to typecheck.  This may be the correct way of doing it, but I don't want to close this answer until I find out that it behaves correctly at runtime.

Comment: @scrapdog look at this question, it might help you too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32623875/connecting-to-mysql-using-slick-3-0-no-username-no-password-and-bogus-driver

Answer (score 1):

I used something similar and it worked for me

```
import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._

def get(id : String) : Future[Channel] = {
implicit val getChannelResult = GetResult(r => Channel(r.<<, r.<<, r.<<, r.<<, r.<<))
val query = sql"select * from Channel where id = $id".as[Channel]
db.run(myq.headOption)
}
```

The **db.run(DBIOAction[T,NoStream,Nothing])** command would accept all types of actions like sqlstreamingaction , StreamingDriverAction , DriverAction etc.

I guess the problem lies with the driver or db configuration. So the error

```
[error]  required: MyDAO.this.driver.api.DBIO[Seq[Int]]
```

Can you just paste the **driver and db configuration steps**, so that we can get a deeper look into the code to identify the actual error step